# Django sqlite "Database is locked" when writing to STATIC_ROOT

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, sqlite, django-models

I have customized the `save()` method of my Django model to write some data into a file. I want to write the data into a file in `STATIC_ROOT` so nginx can serve it. When I write data into a file inside Django project root everything is OK but when I try to write to `STATIC_ROOT` I get "Database is locked error".

What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem but I didn't get why this happens!

To solve the problem when I was overriding the save method of Django model, I first called the `save` method of parent model and then saved my file! Do in reverse order caused the error.